# Load SQL DB in Virtuoso Server

Tags: sql, rdf, virtuoso

The converting strategy DB to RDF  via Virtuoso is mapping OWL class to every table, but in reality for example Person table may be divided to two table "Basic info and extended" for DB design considerations, also many tables is intermediate table for example many to many approch "Person has many diseases and the disease exist in many person".

So must I make changes to DB design before convert it to RDF via Virtuoso e.g "merge Person tables into one and other changes"??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also asked in several other places at roughly the same time, including the [public OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=6083), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/34601031/), a [confidential OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp) (link goes to the case system, not the case itself),

Answers include:

- After linking the remote SQL `TABLEs` into Virtuoso Commercial Edition, you can create a local Virtuoso SQL `VIEW` which `JOINs` the `TABLEs` and `COLUMNs` you want to map to a given OWL class. Virtuoso can automatically generate a Linked Data `VIEW`, and then you can change the generic class and property identifiers to those in your intended niche ontology.
- As you know, Virtuoso's automatically generated Linked Data `VIEWs` include a generic ontology from the SQL `TABLEs` and `VIEWs` you choose.  You can then create a "mapping ontology" between your desired niche ontology (e.g., FOAF) and this generic ontology using `sameAs`, `similarClass`, `equivalentClass`, `similarProperty`, `equivalentProperty`, and similar mapping properties.
- Regarding your concern about Primary Keys vs Foreign Keys -- such table-specific identifiers should be linked with `owl:sameAs` relations -- because, for instance, Primary Key value `1234` from `Users` table `UserID` column and Foreign Key value `1234` from `Users-Extended` table `UserID` **coreference** (that is, refer to) the same entity.  These column identifiers should be linked with `owl:equivalentProperty`.